# How to use activator without fetching activator launcher jar

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I am using activator to build my Play project, and I have one *activator* script and the *activator-launch-1.3.6.jar*; however, when I execute following command

```
./activator dist
```

or

```
java -jar activator-launch-1.3.6.jar dist
```

both actually the same thing;
It will do following thing:

```
Getting com.typesafe.activator activator-launcher 1.3.6 ...
```

My problem is, it is not capable to download the launcher jar; 
So, my first question is:

> How can use activator but not fetching the launcher?

And I am also confused that, I did have the launcher jar,

> why does it fetch it again?

My project structure is like following:

```
sample
   app/
   conf/
   activator.sh
   activator-launch-1.3.6.jar
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you by any chance use Homebrew to install Activator?